# When are stored procedures more performant than queries from application?

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures

Is there ever a performance benefit to stored procedure that can't be achieved without them?

Comment: when are stored procedures more performant... always.

Answer (score 2):

Very large queries can be optimized with a stored procedure, but the difference is usually small.

A large query from an application needs to be transmitted over the wire, then parsed by the SQL server.

Using a stored procedure, the amount of data transmitted can be reduced, and parsing does not need to be performed each time the procedure is called.

Answer (score 1):

When you have to perform more than one query inside the stored procedure.
Assuming two queries - there's the trip back & forth that you can't recoup (assuming the database & application code aren't on the same box -- common in medium to large scale applications).  Plus the concern of managing the transaction...

Not so much a performance concern, but the fact that someone can submit any SQL, besides the security around parameterized queries, is a huge security concern.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking solely about execution time performance (not maintainability) then Stored Procedures generally outperform non-parametrized queries because their execution plan is cached automatically by the SQL server.

Note that parametrized queries as opposed to non-parametrized queries may also be cached by the SQL server but generally speaking it is more likely to get execution plan caching when using stored procedures since that implies that the same query will be used to perform the same task regardless of where you're calling it in an application.